# SXA Site clone - pushing a change from a single site to multiple cloned sites

Tags: sxa

We have a SXA site (say SiteA) (created by a different team and handed over to us). We have to use it and create multiple sites. So we cloned it and create multiple sites (SiteB, SiteC,SiteD), upto 60% of the details will be same across the sites. Is there a way to carry out a change in SiteA such that it percolates to SiteB, C and D immediately? For e.g. updating 'disclaimer' text used by a SXA rendering appearing on the home page of SiteA and the change getting reflected across Site B, C, D without having to make the content item a delegated area. If we have to update multiple content items between master and cloned sites, is delegated area the only option? Please note we are not in a position to change the design of SiteA.

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question or at least put question mark somewhere :) Also why delegated area is not solving your requirement? Seems to me that this is perfect fit....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You should use [Delegated Areas](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/working_with_content/sharing_content/share_content_using_delegated_areas) and [shared site](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/working_with_content/sharing_content/share_data_sources_and_presentation_using_the_multisite_feature) features. It allows you to share presentation (like a page or partial designs, rendering variants, ...) or pages (e.g.: About page looks the same in Site A, Site B and Site C) within the same tenant.

[image]

When you will select e.g.: a page from `Main` site to clone to `Site A`, SXA will show you something like this:

[image]

Just create delegated area and have fun!